# How to resolve parsing error in react js?

Tags: reactjs

I'm a beginner learning through a tutorial and I get the error:

> 'Unexpected token, expected ","'

for the export line no matter what I do. I would appreciate any advice.

```
import React from "react";

const Movie = () => <div 
className="movie">  This is movie 
component </div>;
  
export default Movie;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try putting the component in brackets like this:

```
import React from "react";

const Movie = () => (<div 
className="movie">  This is movie 
component </div>);
  
export default Movie;
```

Comment: I had to restart vscode but it worked. Thank you!